# Spring-boot actuator not working on application port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to access actuator health endpoint in spring boot application on the application port, but it shows me 404-not available when I try to access the below url:
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health

when I set a different management port using the property: management.server.port=9090, then it allows me to access on port 9090.

I need to access actuator on the same port as the application.
Tried setting these properties:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.security.enabled=false
```

but nothing works.
Have this class as well to override the spring security for actuator, which permits unauthorized access to end point /actuator/health.
I have below dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    dependency>
          <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
          <version>5.5.2</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
          <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
          <version>2.6.0</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean? you mean that port 8080 is already in use outside of that springboot code, and you want your springboot also to use 8080?

Comment: port 8080 is not in use anywhere. By default spring boot application runs on port 8080, but actuator does not start on 8080. I do not see actuator end points exposed in the logs like we should have something like:
WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AbstractWebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping$OperationHandler.handle(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to call the actuator as a URL from browser which by default uses GET method . Please try the same URL and hit a post request using any app , you must see a success response .

Comment: I try using curl command like : curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/health . still get the same 404

Comment: Are you getting any response for  localhost:8080/actuator